# How to prevent page from moving down when clicking on Log in button?

Tags: html, css

When clicking on 'Log in' in the top right of this page: http://dev-caal.gotpantheon.com/about, if I click 'Member log in' the page moves so that the box is at the top of the page. How can I have the page stay where it is in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` to the beginning of your onclick function.  The member login link has an anchor link so it is jumping to where the anchor is on the page (at least that's what appears to be happening).